# Visual Studio Online Migration Utility hangs when adding Destination endpoint

Tags: opshub, azure-devops

I downloaded the utility and want to try migrate my TFS on-premise project to Visual Studio online. While adding the Destination endpoint server, I give the url for the online account and I get a window to Sign In to Team Foundation Server and there after a script error comes.
https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20160219T005656/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=0XOnOHTzjeQNmS2N1dMTQZ2JeDL8iUIfvOwf9IJ6Q5Q1

When I try to login through the same user account via web I am able to do so. This user has administrative privileges.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Is this happening on a fresh machine with only IE as the browser?

Comment: @OpsHubInc. Yes, this matches my case. Could that be causing an issue?